# How to autocomplete from dictionary while typing?

Tags: autocompletion, dictionary

I've set a dictionary with the command:

```
set dictionary+=~/Dictionary.txt
```

And add the following command to make more quickly to access it:

```
set complete+=k
```

But I still have to press `<CTRL-N>` to access it.

Is there a way to get the completions as I'm typing? I mean, without having to press any keys to access it. I would like to have it the same way the autocompletion works for words that are in the buffer, they appear in the autocompletion box as I type, without having to press any keys to invoke it.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: FWIW, the "from dictionary" part is irrelevant and could be removed from the question entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting by defining an autocommand.  One of these events seem promising to trigger what you need

```
InsertCharPre   when a character was typed in Insert mode, before inserting it
TextChangedI    after a change was made to the text in Insert mode when popup menu is not visible
```

An autocommand trigged by this event can be a function that triggers auto-completion.  It's likely that you want this function to return early unless a minimum number of characters have been typed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestions. I've tried both events, but I got strange behaviours, nothing close to what I need. The way I did was like that:

`augroup spellComplete  
  autocmd!  
  autocmd TextChangedI * normal <F8>  
augroup END`

obs.: I've mapped F8 to <C-N>